# White Hat Communities

Tags: career

I've been searching Google for a bit and I'm having difficulty finding credible White Hat forums. For example, when one wants to discuss bitcoin they go to bitcointalk, is there a white hat equivalent?

Edit:

My goal is to assemble an appendix of communities that an individual learning about cybersecurity can integrate into to be able to ask questions about identity management, cryptography, good authentication practices (from multifactor to strong passwords), emerging technology that can help people use the web more securely and have better control over their privacy as well as information about the darknet.

I assumed that a white hat community would probably be a wonderful resource; however, there are probably dedicated communities for each.

Comment: There is [chat] - that would seem to do what you want.

Comment: This is a white-hat community.  Even whitehats need to master the dark arts,  or they will be ill-equipped to fight this battle.

Comment: A community under the guidance of the stack exchange format. We can't have discussions nor ask opinions. I'd like a proper forum

Comment: Charles - you can. In chat. It is absolutely for discussions or opinions. We don't want those sort of things on the QA side, as they distract, but in the DMZ anything goes.

Comment: @Rook you have my sword

Comment: @Rook And my bow!

Comment: @Rook And my Queen :(

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman, Simon, Psudeo Reality - You guys are hilarious

Comment: @Rook: I expected someone to add "... and my Hacks!" ^^

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson did you read the comments above by Rook and Rory? Crypto.Se and Security.Se can more than likely answer any questions you may have. Why do you want to hang out on white hat communities only? Black-hat communities have interesting conversations as well.

Comment: @PsudeoReality: Giving away your Queen this long after Freddy's gone makes it rather an empty gesture, don't you think?

Comment: @Rook And you are control all my base

Comment: @Scott Pack I am the king of empty gestures

Answer (score 2):

This is a great community!
Also check these sites out some are community based, some are capture the flag war games which are fun and others just have really good information. There's a ton more out there these are my favorite.

- [Astalavista](http://www.astalavista.com/)
- [HackThisSite](http://www.hackthissite.org/)
- [SmashTheStack](http://smashthestack.org/)
- [Pauldotcom](http://pauldotcom.com/)
- [SecurityWire](http://www.securitywire.com/)
- [PhoneLosers](http://www.phonelosers.com/)
- [social-engineer.org](http://www.social-engineer.org/)

Then there's also the darknet  :) 
It's really what you do with the information you learn from those websites that colors your hat not the website themselves.

> It is said that if you know your enemies and know yourself, you will not be imperiled in a hundred battles; if you do not know your enemies but do know yourself, you will win one and lose one; if you do not know your enemies nor yourself, you will be imperiled in every single battle.

-Sun Tzu